# What's the usage of the three boot mode of STM32f103?

Tags: memory, stm32

If you see in refrence manual of STM32f103, you can see three boot mode for it. well, What's the usage of the three boot mode?

[image: modes]

please say to me by example for each mode.

Comment: Interestingly, if you design your own PCB, and dislike bulky jumpers for boot0 and boot1, you just can use a push button for boot0 to switch between system and flash memory.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Booting from System Memory invokes the on-chip bootloader, which is present in the chip directly from the factory, before you've programmed anything into the on-chip flash.  This allows you to load (program) code into the device from an external interface such as UART or USB.  This is explained in detail in the manual.

Main flash memory is where your code typically goes.  In normal operation, your code will reside in flash, and on Power On Reset (POR), the CPU will fetch the reset vector and initial stack pointer (SP) from flash.  You can load flash via JTAG, on-chip bootloader (above), etc.

Lastly, you can load code into RAM (JTAG, runtime) and then boot/run from there.  This isn't often used, usually you're doing something tricky like a temporary bootloader or the like.